# reload views after changing the locale in android

Tags: android, locale

I want to change the locale in my android app so I used the following code :

```
Locale locale = new Locale('fr'); // or whatever
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;

getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

But the problem is that nothing changes in my views. How should I reload them to make the locale change visible?

Edit : every views are affected : buttons, textviews, checkboxes. of course if I manually set the text for the view then it works but I dont want to call setText() on every widgets... I know it because the username is displayed in a view and it wasn't updating after a log off / log on with another user. So I updated the textview manually but after I found that the problem was the same for every views when changinf the locale.

Comment: First of all, do you have the tranlations for the strings you are using?

Comment: of course, I have en, fr and nl in the folders values-en, values-fr, values-nl

Comment: Can you tell the types of the affected Views? Are they TextView, EditText, CheckBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are asking how to "reload" the `Activity` you are on when changing the locale.

As far as I know, you have to re-layout / recreate the `View`s or re-set the text in them. If, however, you find a better solution, please share it.

Comment: finally I made the app close to be sure every views are reloaded after locale change.

Comment: @jafar How restarting your app solves your problems. Consider a tabbed app, where you previous state may loss.

Comment: @jafar can you please explain how you solved this issue. Please reply.

Answer (score 0):

Allright I found a solution to this and would like to share.
add this to your manifest

```
android:configChanges="locale"
```

and override onConfigurationChanged() in your activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  // refresh your views here
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

go [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) for more info.
Hope it helps. :)